# Create or Reshape OpenCV 3 Channel Mat From Array

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to build a 3 channel matrix from a 1D array of data of **arbitrary data type, row dimension, column dimension, and channel dimension**. In my example, I have a 1x12 double array of data, and I want to transform it into a 2x2x3 OpenCv matrix.

```
double rawData[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0};
```

**My goal** is to to have :

```
Channel 1:
[  1,   1;
   1,   1]
Channel 2:
[  2,   2;
   2,   2]
Channel 3:
[  3,   3;
   3,   3]
```

This is what I've tried:

```
cv::Mat aMat = cv::Mat(2, 2, CV_64FC3, rawData)
```

But OpenCv doesn't agree with how it should use that `rawData` buffer. When I split the matrix by channels and print each individual channel with :

```
cv::Mat channels[3];
cv::split(aMat ,channels);
```

It does:

```
Channel 1:
[  1,   1;
   2,   3]

Channel 2:
[  1,   2;
   2,   3]

Channel 3:
[  1,   2;
   3,   3]
```

I've also tried loading the data in a 1D Mat and then using cv::Reshape but the result is the same.

How can I get the channels to look the way I want? Do I really have to manually assign every index or is there a more elegant/optimized way?

Edit: **Problem Constraints**

The order of the data in rawData should not be rearranged, as that would introduce additional complexity to determine the dimensions and data type. I would prefer to use OpenCV interfaces if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just rearrange your data:

```
double rawData[] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
```

or build seperate 'channel' Mats from your data, and later merge:

```
double rawData[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
                    2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0,
                    3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0};
Mat chan[3] = {
    Mat(2,2,CV_64F, rawData),
    Mat(2,2,CV_64F, rawData+4),
    Mat(2,2,CV_64F, rawData+8)
};

Mat merged;
cv::merge(chan,3,merged);
```

Comment: I would prefer not to rearrange the raw data. It's coming in as void*, and I would not like to sniff out what type it is, cast the data, and then rearrange accordingly. If there were an option that I could use to specify the order of populating the matrix, ie rows, cols, channels, that would be ideal.

Comment: you probably need at least *some* knowledge about your input data. it's not 'arbitrary' as you say.

Comment: Well of course there's metadata associated with it, or else how would I specify the CV_64F* field? I can rearrange the data but I would prefer not to. It is arbitrary in a sense that the incoming data can be any data type and dimension.

Comment: your example already assumed consecutive channel data (not interleaved, like most 'pixels'

Comment: I literally did this independently. Gave you the correct answer since it's what I'm sticking with. See my answer as well.

Answer (score 3):

My solution is close to berak's, with splitting the data into separate channels. Except one important (I think) difference. I initialize a single row matrix with the datatype already encoded, ie:

```
cv::Mat aMat = cv::Mat(1, 12, CV_64F, data);
```

I then use the colRange method to extract parts of the column:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> channelVector(3);
channelVector[0] = aMat.colRange(0,4);
channelVector[1] = aMat.colRange(4,8);
channelVector[2] = aMat.colRange(8,12);
```

I do this to avoid pointer arithmetic. The strength here is that I can have my data buffer be of type `void*` and I do not have to worry about first casting the pointer to the correct type in order to increment the buffer pointer.

I then iterate with some reshape action.

```
for(cv::Mat& channel : channelVector)
    channel = channel.reshape(1,2);
```

And finally merge.

```
cv::Mat combinedMatrix;
cv::merge(channelVector, combinedMatrix);
```

This should be efficient, as these operations are O(1). I'm not sure about the merge, I think that actually copies data but I can't verify that... but I was going to `clone()` the final result anyway, so that works out for me.